# what is the need of parsing resource id using ContextCompat class?

Tags: java, android

In the code below I want to return the resource id of a certain color depending upon the cases in `getMagnitudeColor()` method.
So, if I return them directly like this

```
private int getMagnitudeColor(double magnitude){
    int roundOffMagnitude = (int)Math.floor(magnitude);

    switch(roundOffMagnitude){
        case 1: return R.color.magnitude1;
        case 2: return R.color.magnitude2;
        case 3: return R.color.magnitude3;
        case 4: return R.color.magnitude4;
        case 5: return R.color.magnitude5;
        case 6: return R.color.magnitude6;
        case 7: return R.color.magnitude7;
        case 8: return R.color.magnitude8;
        case 9: return R.color.magnitude9;

        default: return R.color.magnitude10plus;

    }
```

[image: image of the above code]

then my app is not working later I found out that I've to do something like this:

```
private int getMagnitudeColor(double magnitude) {
    int magnitudeColorResourceId;
    int magnitudeFloor = (int) Math.floor(magnitude);
    switch (magnitudeFloor) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude1;
            break;
        case 2:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude2;
            break;
        case 3:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude3;
            break;
        case 4:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude4;
            break;
        case 5:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude5;
            break;
        case 6:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude6;
            break;
        case 7:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude7;
            break;
        case 8:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude8;
            break;
        case 9:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude9;
            break;
        default:
            magnitudeColorResourceId = R.color.magnitude10plus;
            break;
    }

    return ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), magnitudeColorResourceId);
}
```

[image: image for the above code]

I know `ContextCompat.getColor` is used to parse the color resource id but my question is that if both resource id and the value returned by `ContextCompat.getColor()` is an integer then what is the need to use `ContextCompat.getColor()` method.

Comment: So you ask why `return something` is different than `return someCallToSomeMehtod(something)`? You should not look at the return type but at the return value. `return 0` does return an `int` as well but will probably not work properly either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` returned by `ContextCompat.getColor()` is actually the color you want (an hexadecimal color as an integer), in most case you will be asked for that color. The R.color.xxx `int` is actually just a ID referencing you hexadecimal/integer color from your resources, dependening on API your are using you may be asked for that id but behind the scene there will be certainly a `ContextCompat.getColor()` from that id.